# How to find out which territory's App Store the running app came from?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Is there a way of working out which territory's App Store the running app came from?

I would like to set certain preferences and links in the app according to the territory it is being used in, and I would prefer not to use the GPS if possible.

At the moment our best bet seems to be to examine the phone's locale.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible or clever. I'm living in Germany and own many apps from the us store I got as present or because they are only available there.

Comment: It would be a way of setting a sensible default, that can be altered by the user, so it shouldn't cause problems in that scenario.

Comment: what about making a network call and use an ip location database ?

Comment: I thought about the network call - but I think @Jasarien has a good point, below. It is more about your locale preferences than where you actually are at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the device's current locale would be the proper way to do this.

There is no way you can find out which app store region the app was downloaded from.

Also, the locale will tell you which language/region settings the user prefers, where the GPS or current location would only tell you where they are.

For example, I have my iPhone set to the United Kingdom as the locale, but I may go on holiday to France. If I downloaded an app while in France, I wouldn't want it to be set up for French users just because that's where I am.

The locale is a user chosen preference, it doesn't change as the user changes location.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to get user's appstore country when your app finish request IAP products.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSArray *products = response.products;
    SKProduct *product = products.lastObject;

    if (product) {
        NSLocale* storeLocale = product.priceLocale;
        // Get it!
        NSString *storeCountry = (NSString*)CFLocaleGetValue((CFLocaleRef)storeLocale, kCFLocaleCountryCode);

    }
}
```